# I need my javascript timer to stop at 0, display a msg, and then restart

Tags: javascript, timertask

I have created  a javascript timer that starts at 40 and counts  down by one, but it wont stop at 0 and i want it to display a message(not an alert)/add an item to a database when it hits 0, and then restart at 40 seconds. If you could provide any help, thanks in advance :D

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=40;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c-1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
{
timer_is_on=1;
timedCount();
}
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="doTimer()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
</form>
<p>Click on the button above. It will count down from 40</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should set your timer_is_on to true and false instead of 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use setInterval rather than setTimeout as this will fire the method periodically according to the delay you specify.

This will restart the timer when the count hits 0:

```
    function timedCount() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
        c = c - 1;
        if (c == 0)
            c = 40;
    }

    function doTimer() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = true;
            t = setInterval(function () {
                timedCount();
            }, 1000);                
        }
    }
```

If you want to stop the timer when the count hits 0 use this:

```
    function timedCount() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
        c = c - 1;
        if (c == 0) {
            c = 40;
            clearInterval(t); // Stops the interval
        }
    }
```